# Показ картинки по событию onchange

Tags: html, css, javascript

```
    <head>
<style type="text/css">
       .image {
        width: 200px; /* ширина блока с картинками */
        height: 200px; /* высота */
        position: absolute; /* абсолютное позиционирование */
        left: 150px; /* смещение от левого края */
        top: 10px; /* смещение от верха */
        border: 1px #cc6633 solid; /* стили рамки */
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div>
       <select onchange="document.getElementById('image').src=this.value">
         <option value="none">Шоколадки</option>
         <option value="http://spravka.seodon.ru/spravka/html/sobytiya/primer/images/cat.png">Кошка</option>
         <option value="http://spravka.seodon.ru/spravka/html/sobytiya/primer/images/dog.png">Собачка</option>
         <option value="http://spravka.seodon.ru/spravka/html/sobytiya/primer/images/rabbit.png">Кролик</option>
       </select>
      </div>
      <div class="image"><img id="image" src="#" alt=""></div>
    </body>
```

Нашел подходящий пример показа картинки по событию select, все работает, но мне нужно value использовать для передачи значения в форме, пробовал использовать label, но не получилось. Подскажите, как можно реализовать показ картинки по переключению <select..., но чтобы можно было значение передать value. Такое возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rj3tLth3/ Посмотри. Я переписал чуть код на jquery (не забудь подключить библиотеку)

в value будем хранить значение, а в data-img теперь ссылка на картинку, которую нужно показать

Comment: Заработало! Супер, спасибо.